# openstack instance getting ip and not getting ip

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I am new to openstack and I followed the installation guide of icehouse for ubuntu 12.04/14.04

I chose 3 node architecture. Controller, Nova, Neutron.

The 3 nodes are installed in VM's. I used nested KVM. Inside VM's kvm is supported so nova will use virt_type=kvm. In controller I created 2 nics. eth0 is a NAT interface with ip 203.0.113.94 and eth1 a host only interface with ip 10.0.0.11.

In nova there are 3 nics. eth0 NAT - 203.0.113.23, eth1 host only 10.0.0.31 and eth2 another host only 10.0.1.31

In neutron 3 nics. eth0 NAT 203.0.113.234, eth1 host only 10.0.0.21 and eth2 another hosty only 10.0.1.21 (during installation guide in neutron node i created a br-ex (and a port to eth0) which took the settings of eth0 and eth0 settings are:

```
auto eth0 iface eth0 inet manual up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
up ip link set $IFACE promisc on
down ip link set $IFACE promisc off
down ifconfig $IFACE down)
```

Everything seemed fine. I can create networks, routers etc, boot instances but I have this error.

When I launch an instance it takes a fixed ip but when I log in into instance (cirros) can't ping anything. ifconfig with no ip.

I noticed that in demo-net (tenant network) properties under subnet in the ports field it has 3 ports. 172.16.1.1 network:router_interface active 172.16.1.3 network:dhcp active 172.16.1.6 compute:nova down

I searched for solutions over the net but couldn't find anything!

Any help?

Ask me if you want specific logs because I don't know which ones to post!

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Also, check the security group rules. After associating floating IP, to be able to Ping you should add ICMP rule with Direction: Ingress. Plus, you can find answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795057/openstack-networking-cant-ping-ssh-from-to-vms?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Fixed IP to ping..If so please assign floating IP to your instance, and then try to ping..
If you have already assigned floating IP and you are pinging using that IP..please upload log of your instance